# Blending between particles and sprites

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a problem with blending particles and sprites. Take a look:
[Particle above the sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NNhi.png)

`SpriteMaterial` and `PointsMaterial` have blending `THREE.AdditiveBlending`. Whats wrong with this?

Between particles i see the same problem, when they overlap each other.
[Primer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71YOv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

friends! If you can't solve this problem, try set `depthWrite: false` on your material with blending. This should helps you! For me it's a good solution.